# How can I ensure that a dynamic table gives the proper percentage of space to each column?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a dynamic table which could grow up to 6 rows.

I want to ensure that the columns are always equally-spaced, like `50-50` if there are `2`, or `33-33-33` if there are `3`, or `25-25-25-25` if there are `4`.

Here is an example of the table: https://codepen.io/maketroli/pen/pZvXoJ

The css for the table starts on the `line 94`.
In the line 104 I have this: `width: 50%;` because at the beginning the table was only 2 columns but now the game changed.

Also I am using handlebars so maybe there could be a solution with that too.

```
{{#with table}}
    <table class="submasthead-item__table">
        {{#if headings}}
            <thead>{{#each headings}}<th>{{{this}}}</th>{{/each}}</thead>
        {{/if}}
        <tbody>
        {{#each values}}
            <tr>
                {{#eachIndex this}}
                    <td {{#is ../../text-red true}}{{#is index 1}}class="text--brightRed"{{/is}}{{/is}}>
                        {{item}}
                    </td>
                {{/eachIndex}}
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{{/with}}
```

So, how can I calculate that?

**UPDATE:**

I can not use flexbox for this table. Is a requirement because it gives issues with accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like `<tr class="col-{{array.length}}"><th>...</th></tr>` to print how many of columns will be looped, and then assign the CSS:

```
tr.col-2 th {
   width: 50%;
}
tr.col-3 th {
   width: 33.334%;
}
tr.col-4 th {
   width: 25%;
}
tr.col-5 th {
   width: 20%;
}
```

and so on...